# Halacha seforim on tefila

Tags: halacha, tefilla, product-recommendation, jewish-books, english

Would anyone know of an English, practical sefer on the halachos of *Birchos Krias Shema* and the rest of tefila (i.e. *Shmoneh Esrei* , etc. ? )

Comment: what are you looking for exactly,because they make an English Mishna Bruah and Kitzur Shulchan Aruch which discusses these topics in detail

Answer (score 2):

Artscroll has a very good [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422611043.html) over three volumes for the basic halacha, but it is hard to ready from cover to cover, and still quite complex. Some people have a practice to read a few pages a day until they cover the whole sefer - then start again - it is an excellent way to have a general overview of all practical laws and know where to look deeper. Also exists on the iPad now.

The [Laws of Daily Living](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422605417.html) by R Simcha Bunim Cohen is likely closer to what you are looking for. I have read all his Shabbat halacha books and he writes in a practical and easy to understand style. Check the table of contents though (at link above) as he stops at psukei dezimra in volume 1 and volume 2 is not out yet.

So it looks like your best bet for a simple halacha book covering all basic laws is [Shaarei Halachah by R Zeev Greenwald](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583304347) or [here](http://www.feldheim.com/shaarei-halachah.html)

Comment: There's also [a _Kitzur Shulchan Aruch_ translation by Rabbi A. Davis, published by Metsudah](http://www.worldcat.org/search?qt=worldcat_org_bks&q=davis+kitzur&fq=dt%3Abks). I have never opened it AFAIR, so cannot recommend it.

Comment: I have it and it is a good translation. It has Hebrew and English text. But it has near to zero explanation or commentary so much less easier to relate to current halacha than he new artscroll version.

Answer (score 2):

For an in-depth book in English: Hilchot Tefillah by R. David Brofsky https://www.ou.org/oupress/product/hilchot-tefilla-a-comprehensive-guide-to-the-laws-of-daily-prayer/